It cannot show the absolute .webp file in the browser if I "open with live server" in vscode, local html files are fine
Compiler: VS Code
My file directory of my open folder is on D drive, I tried to show a picture which in E drive by using absolute path.
In the index.html file, my part code is:
<img src="E:\desktop\1.webp" alt="1" />

but it cannot shows in browser.
It shows like this: 
But if I open this html file locally, the image is displayed normally.
This means that my compiler VSCODE can't open absolute paths, so I need a solution.
I tried the first method:
Add the file protocol in script, but it doesn't work:
<img src="file://E:\desktop\1.webp" alt="1" />


Opening it in VSC is probably opening http://localhost:…, right? You cannot refer to local files in this case. Only a file://… page can refer to other files. You’ll need to bring the files you want into the same directory so VSC can serve them as well. At least with a symlink.

Thank you for your advice, if I put them in the same directory, the relative path works, but now I want my absolute path works, how can I do...

There are MANY tutorials explaining how to include images in web pages and how to organise your web files/assets in general.

You should not be using paths to files on your local drive(s) like that.
You need to refer to the image locations relative to the web folder of your website. Typically, if you are running Apache for example, you would have htdocs as your root folder containing your web pahes. You would then most likely arrange your images in a subfolder, htdocs/img.
If your page is in htdocs you would then refer to an image in htdocs/img like so:

